# Count elements in bash wildcard expansion?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a simple loop in one of my data processing scripts that looks something like this ...

```
for f in *.dat; do
  process ${f}
done
```

I'd like to build in a status indicator, so I'd like to be able to count the number of elements in `*.dat`, but I can't find any clues and Google isn't exactly friendly to this sort of search.

Comment: Not entirely related to your question, but don't forget to quote `"${f}"`, to deal with files containing whitespace or globbing characters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With Bash arrays:

```
arr=(*.dat)
count=${#arr[@]}
```

To break this down, `${arr[@]}` gives you every element in the array, and `#` gives you the count in the parameter expansion (actually it'd give you the string length, but for arrays it's the count).

See also, on the Bash Hackers Wiki:

- [Arrays](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays)
- [Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#string_length)